# How to compare two encrypted(bcrypt) password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bcrypt

How to compare two bcrypt password

```
$pass1 = '$2y$10$ooPG9s1lcwUGYv1nqeyNcO0ccYJf8hlhm5dJXy7xoamvgiczXHB7S';
```

And

```
$pass2 = '$2y$10$QRgaiS6bpATKKQeT22zGKuHq.edDfXQc2.4B3v.zaN.GtGwoyQuMy';
```

Both $pass1 & $pass2 are bcrypt for 'test'.

How I can check for equality. without using text 'test' like this

```
$hash1 = Hash::make('test');
$hash2 = Hash::make('test');

var_dump(Hash::check('test', $hash1) && Hash::check('test', $hash2));
```

Comment: Take a look at this, bro. [Laravel Hash explanation](https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't actually compare two encrypted bcrypt passwords to each other directly as strings because the encryption contains salt which makes the hashes different each time.

Comment: 'test' is only for example, actually all password is stored in db and I can't decrypt again to compare, any other alternative to check.

Comment: That's what I mean, though. You can't compare the encrypted passwords directly. You can run Hash::check() on each one if you know what the original password is but it's impossible to compare two bcrypted passwords. I've updated my answer to simplify the situation.

Comment: This is right answer for the questions. They can NOT compare with two encrypted passwords.

Answer (score 34):

```
if(Hash::check('plain-text-password',$cryptedpassword)) {
    // Right password
} else {
    // Wrong one
}
```

Comment: The OP asks how to compare two *encrypted* passwords in a situation where the original plain text passwords are unknown. However, this answer only compares a known plain text password.

Comment: The OP asked how to compare two encrypted password, without the possibility to access to the original plain text password. This is the reason I downvoted the response

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `Hash::check()` method
eg:

```
if(Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    return true;
}
```

reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing

Comment: The OP asks how to compare two encrypted passwords in a situation where the original plain text passwords are unknown. However, this answer only compares a known plain text password.

Comment: The OP asked how to compare two encrypted password, without the possibility to access to the original plain text password. This is the reason I downvoted the response

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

[PHP Manual on crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) (ref: example 1)

```
<?php
// 1. for compare two crypted string
// ----------
// let the salt be automatically generated; not recommended
$hashed_password = crypt('mypassword');

/* You should pass the entire results of crypt() as the salt for comparing a
password, to avoid problems when different hashing algorithms are used. (As
it says above, standard DES-based password hashing uses a 2-character salt,
but MD5-based hashing uses 12.) */
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}

// 2. for compare with normal text
// ----------
if (Hash::check('test', bcrypt('test'))) {
    return 'match!!';
}else{
    return 'not match!!';
}
```

Comment: The OP asks how to compare two encrypted passwords in a situation where the original plain text passwords are unknown. However, this answer only compares a known plain text password.

Comment: The OP asked how to compare two encrypted password, without the possibility to access to the original plain text password. This is the reason I downvoted the response

Comment: Sorry for that now I have updated post with correct answer as per query. Thanks @Joseph

Answer (score -1):

you can compare hash encrypt the password using **`Hash`**.

but note that in this method 
the first value should be **`plain-text`** and second **`bcrypt`** value.

```
Hash::check('test', bcrypt('test'))
```

Comment: The OP asks how to compare two encrypted passwords in a situation where the original plain text passwords are unknown. However, this answer only compares a known plain text password.

Comment: The OP asked how to compare two encrypted password, without the possibility to access to the original plain text password